# How to add new object (forms)?

Tags: django, django-forms

I Have form:

```
class ProjektForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

and view:

```
@login_required
def add_new(request):
    data = dict()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    data.update({ 'form': form })

    t = loader.get_template('form.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, data)
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

but when I click "submit" - system show me error: "id is required". It's new object and have no "id".

How to do it? And is it possible to make adding and editing objects in one view?

Comment: What is MyForm? Also post the error traceback

Comment: Is that a typo? 'MyForm' should be 'ProjektForm'

Comment: I've tested this code (I changed Myform to ProjectForm) and it works successful, perhaps Nips you have a problem in an another place, you should post the error traceback and more code (there aren't model).

Comment: Yes, my fault, sorry for that. Close please.